# Updating value 0 instead of array in the table of multiple checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The form updates the value 0 in the database, it should update the array of check boxes but it's not working. 
I've updated the controller and view, please take a look and check if possible.

Controller

```
function type()
  {
if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
{
$userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
$data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
$data['title'] = 'Type | Categories';
$type=$this->form_validation->set_rules('type[]', 'Type', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $data['categories'] = $this->category_model->get_categories();
    $data['main_view']="users/v_type";
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
    $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar',$data);
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer',$data);
} else {
    // Encrypt password

    $type = $this->input->post('type');
    $this->m_user->type($type);
}else
{
     redirect(base_url().'user/');
}
}
```

View

```
 <form action="<?=  base_url()?>user/type" method="post">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Textile " name="type[]">Textile </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Textile2 " name="type[]">Textile2 </label>
</form>
```

Model

```
public function type(){
            if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
    {
       $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
      $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
    $type = $this->input->post('type');
    $data=array('type'=>json_encode(implode(",", $type)),);
        $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
        return $this->db->update('users', $data);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what is your question?

Comment: is this you controller or model... plz explain your code

Comment: I've mentioned Model, Please check @Ash

Comment: @Roshan, I've updated the controller and view in it. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is, issue is in $data parameter 

 `$data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID); //fetching in parameter data
  $type = $this->input->post('type');
  $data=array('type'=>json_encode(implode(",", $type)),); //this should have some column like $data['type'] maybe
  }`

Comment: Got it! you are passing in controller like this `$this->m_user->type($type);` and in model you are using post that will not get anything. So pass  type as parameter in model then update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this your **Updated Model Function code**, and tell me what you find

```
public function type(){
    //If already logged in
    if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))
    {
        $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
        $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
        $type = $this->input->post('type');
        echo'<pre>';print_r($type);
        $data=array('type'=>json_encode(implode(",", $type)),);
        echo'<pre>';print_r($data);
        $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
        $flag = $this->db->update('users', $data);
        echo $flag;die;
    }
}
```